# Whose photo is on the table in the telephone call scene?

Tags: props, the-sacrifice

It's hard to believe that a detail in a [Tarkovsky](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrei_Tarkovsky) film is
arbitrary.

In [The Sacrifice (Offret)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sacrifice), there is a scene at the 2:00:00 mark, where the main character is sitting at a table facing the camera. On the right hand side there are 3 bottles and there is a small portrait of a man on the left hand side:

[image]

Who is the man in the photograph and why is this important?  Why was this photograph included?

Comment: Not knowing anything about the movie, why does the picture look like Hitler?